# How to concatenate a variable name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want the following call to my function

```
MakeMargin(unit1)
```

To ouput the following variable ( not a string ! ):

```
theme.spacing.unit1
```

I tried the following :

```
function MakeMargin(props) {
  const output = theme.spacing + props

  return (
    output
  );
}
```

Comment: Vote to close because this question is unclear.  Please share i.e: error output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Also, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Meta_programming)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to output the content of that variable or the variable itself? I mean, are we talking about metaprogramming?

Comment: Probably the OP wants to pass a String, i.e: `MakeMargin("unit1")` and within `MakeMargin` returns `"theme.spacing" + props`.  It's unclear!"

Comment: @ele judging from the comment to faly's answer I'm afraid we are both wrong.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, the question is asking for concatenation and not for object accessing.  It's unclear.

Comment: I wasn't sure that concatenation was the right term here. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
function MakeMargin(props) {
    return theme.spacing[props]
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to concatenate. It's unclear what the OP has asked.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: @Romainpetit that's not what you've asked.  This answer doesn't answer what you wrote in your question.